# Checking Dates in Excel VBA Dictionary

Tags: excel, date, dictionary, if-statement, vba

I'm currently using a dictionary to hold a list of bank holidays. I want to check if the current-1 date is a bank holiday and if so check if the previous day was a bank holiday and then if 3 days previous was a bank holiday (e.g. Monday is a bank holiday and so was the previous Friday)?

I'm having problems checking for dates in the Dictionary. I can compare strings (declare Date as string so my IF query works) BUT I cant then -1 or -3 from this date because it is a string.

Can anyone advise me of how to check dates in my below code please?

```
Public currentDate As Long
Public Bankholiday As Boolean
Public DoubleBank As Boolean
Public asdfg As Date
Public currentDay As String
Public BankHolidays As Scripting.Dictionary
Public DiaryDate As String
```

Then the sub is

```
Sub GetDate()
'Created to determin if a Bank Holiday needs to be taken into account for 
Date to run

currentDate = Date - 1
Today = Date - 1
currentDay = Format(Date, "dddd") 'writes day out as string e.g. Monday, 
Tuesday....
currentDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") 'set format for SQL query
DiaryDate = Format(Date - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")

'Set Dictionary Object
Set BankHolidays = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


'Add dates to Dictionary
BankHolidays.Add "01/01/2017", "B1"
BankHolidays.Add "02/05/2017", "B2"
BankHolidays.Add "14/04/2017", "B3"
BankHolidays.Add "17/04/2017", "B4"
BankHolidays.Add "01/05/2017", "B5"
BankHolidays.Add "29/05/2017", "B6"
BankHolidays.Add "28/08/2017", "B7"
BankHolidays.Add "25/12/2017", "B8"
BankHolidays.Add "26/12/2017", "B9"
BankHolidays.Add "01/01/2018", "B10"
BankHolidays.Add "30/03/2018", "B11"
BankHolidays.Add "02/04/2018", "B12"
BankHolidays.Add "07/05/2018", "B13"
BankHolidays.Add "28/05/2018", "B14"
BankHolidays.Add "27/08/2018", "B15"
BankHolidays.Add "25/12/2018", "B16"
BankHolidays.Add "26/12/2018", "B17"
BankHolidays.Add "04/05/2017", "B18"
BankHolidays.Add "03/05/2017", "B18"

'Check if Todays Date is in the dictionary
If BankHolidays.Exists(DiaryDate) Then
Today = Today - 1
MsgBox "1"
    'For instances of 2 consecutive bankholidays in a row (no weekend in     between)
    If BankHolidays.Exists(Today) Then
        Today = currentDate - 1
        MsgBox "2"
    End If

'For instances of 2 consecutive bankholidays in a row (WITH weekend in     between)
            If BankHolidays.Exists(Today - 2) Then
                Today = currentDate - 1
                MsgBox "3"
            End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following works converting the variable type. Might not be the best or most elegant way but seems to work:
Note 1 new variable DiaryDate1 As Date was needed

Code below:

```
DiaryDate1 = CDate(DiaryDate)   'Pass DiaryDate1 the value of DiaryDate converted to a Date type
DiaryDate1 = DiaryDate1 - 2     'Minus 2 days from DiaryDate1
DiaryDate = CStr(DiaryDate1)    'Set DiaryDate the value of DiaryDate1 converted to a string type
```

Comment: Not tested but would the following work also? `DiaryDate = CStr(CDate(DiaryDate)-2)`